# Calling an external REST service in apex

Tags: api, rest-service, xml, httpcalloutmock

I need to make a call to an external xml-rpc service in apex. I have written this little apex code:

```
public static void callPBA() {

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();

    req.setEndpoint('https://external.service.com');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody('');
    req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000

    try {
        res = http.send(req);
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    }

}
```

but I don't know how to test it. Any ideas?
And how can I set the body to read from an xml file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In order to **test the callout** you should implement a `HttpCalloutMock` ([official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm)) to emulate the remote service, then set it in your test class

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new YourHttpCalloutMockImpl());
```

Regarding to **read the XML response**, I recommend you to use de `Dom` class ([official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_xml_dom.htm))

Sample of how to read the response:

```
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();

        //Retrieve the root element for this document.
        Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();

        String name = address.getChildElement('name', null).getText();
        String state = address.getChildElement('state', null).getText();
        // print out specific elements
        System.debug('Name: ' + name);
        System.debug('State: ' + state);

        // Alternatively, loop through the child elements.
        // This prints out all the elements of the address
        for(Dom.XMLNode child : address.getChildElements()) {
           System.debug(child.getText());
        }
```

Comment: Reading your links I see how to create a fake response, but how can I get the real one and test it this works?

Comment: You could select any public service to test your callout, google is your friend:   https://www.google.es/search?q=public%20xml%20weather%20feed , sample: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=show%20tables&diagnostics=true

Comment: @Martin I don't think you can do actual callouts in test execution context. Tony, this is to make sure your tests are reliable and won't fail if the external system fails.

Comment: What I mean is: I need to make a call to a service I know in apex. How can I see if my call works.

Comment: @Sdry: of course you cant. I thought he is trying to test the code on a real external service by user trigged execution context (ex sandbox).

Comment: @tonydanza: try the read code I've posted. There you have a system.debug where you could see the callout response